# Launching the phone from HTML5 or Cordova

Tags: html, cordova

Does anyone know if it is possible using HTML5 or Cordova (PhoneGap) to launch a phone number?  I'd like to have a button labeled "Call 555-555-5555", and when pressed, it launches the device's phone with that number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the html tel scheme like this:

```
<a href="tel:555-555-5555">Call 555-555-5555</a>
```

For more detail check this [Click to Call link](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers)

Comment: Ok, great - I'll give that a try!